# Graphical Python Password Generator : tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a password generator using tkinter.
I did the non-graphical version, so I thought to make a graphical version. When I run it, they show this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/biswa/OneDrive/Documents/Python/Graphical Password Generator.py", line 20, in <module>
    welcome_text=Label("Welcome to my graphical password generator" ,fg='red', bg='yellow')
  File "C:\Users\biswa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3143, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Users\biswa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2561, in __init__
    BaseWidget._setup(self, master, cnf)
  File "C:\Users\biswa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2530, in _setup
    self.tk = master.tk
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tk'
```

Here is the code:

```
symbols=['!','@','#','$','%','^','&','*','(',')','~','`']
numbers=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
words=['a','b','c','d','e''f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p']

from tkinter import *
def generate():

   print((random.choice(numbers)+
   random.choice(words)+random.choice(symbols)+
   random.choice(numbers)+random.hhoice(words +
   random.choice(words)+random.choice(numbers)+
   random.choice(symbols)+random.choice(words)

   screen=Tk()
   screen.title("Graphical Password generator")
   screen.geometry('400x400')

   welcome_text=Label("Welcome to my graphical password generator" ,fg='red', bg='yellow')
   welcome_text.pack

   generate=Button(text='Generate', fg='red', bg='yellow', command=generate)
   generate.place(x=30, y=40)

   name_storage=StringVar()
   name=Entry(textvariable=name_storage)
   name.pack()
   screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: You omitted the first argument to `Label`.  That causes your program to fault at run time.  Read the [documentation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_label.htm), follow the examples, etc.  When you post a problem, we expect a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with a reasonable trace of pertinent values.  Most of your posted code is unrelated to the problem.

Comment: You passed the text of the label as the first argument to `Label()` which is supposed to be the parent of the label, so it should be `Label(screen, text="...", ...)`.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code so that it works:

```py
import random
from tkinter import *
symbols=['!','@','#','$','%','^','&','*','(',')','~','`']
numbers=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
words=['a','b','c','d','e''f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p']


def generate():

   print(str(random.choice(numbers))+
         random.choice(words)+
         random.choice(symbols)+
         str(random.choice(numbers))+
         random.choice(words)+
         random.choice(words)+
         str(random.choice(numbers))+
         random.choice(symbols)+
         random.choice(words))

screen = Tk()
screen.title("Graphical Password generator")
screen.geometry('400x400')

welcome_text=Label(screen, text = "Welcome to my graphical password generator" ,fg='red', bg='yellow')
welcome_text.pack()

generate=Button(screen, text='Generate', fg='red', bg='yellow', command=generate)
generate.place(x=30, y=40)

name_storage=StringVar()
name=Entry(screen, textvariable=name_storage)
name.pack()
screen.mainloop()
```

Note: Tested in Python 3.7.7